# Running NYPL's Map-vectorizor in Ubuntu - GIMP scripting errors

Tags: bash, scripts, gimp

I hope this is the right place to ask this question

I recently endeavored to digitize a bunch of old maps and I aim to use NYPL's map-vectorizer tool that was written inside a Mac. The aforementioned code is linked below.

https://github.com/NYPL/map-vectorizer

My error was after meeting all dependencies it could not open the file-load-tiff script within GIMP-2.6 no matter which particular flavor of gimp (gimp, gimp-console, gimp-console-2.6, etc) and it keeps giving me the same error:

```
> Thresholdizing:
> ---------------
> test.ti/test.tif into threshold file: test.ti/test/test-threshold-tmp.tif
> 
> (gimp:17828): GLib-WARNING **: (/build/buildd/glib2.0- 2.32.3/./glib/gerror.c:390):g_error_new_valist: runtime check failed: (domain != 0)
> GIMP-Error: Execution error for procedure 'file-tiff-load':
> Could not open 'test.ti/test.tif' for reading: No such file or directory

> batch command experienced an execution error

> ERROR 4: `test.ti/test.tif' does not exist in the file system,
> and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

> gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'test.ti/test.tif'.
```

Now I understand everything after the GIMP-error is just failscade - but I am totally new to gimp scripting and am unsure of how to ensure a stable connection between the multiple scripts that make up this tool and my Gimp installation. I have tried this across two machines, My Ubuntu VM sitting inside x64 windows 7 install and an ARM processor Chromebook running Precise Pangolin through Crouton.

Update 17/10/2013

There was a typo inside the nypl-create-threshold.scm which called file-tif-load. Also the invocation of GIMP was missing the flags -i and -b in `config.py` This can be fixed by adjusting the line:

```
    defaultgimp = '/usr/bin/gimp -i -b'
```

These two fixes have advanced me to a new error where the temporary generation of thresholdized tifs is breaking and deleting their .tmp files before allowing the rest of the script to use them.

```
man@squid:~/map-vectorizer$ ./vectorize_map.py test.tif 






NYPL Labs Map Vectorizer v0.1 
=============================
By: Mauricio Giraldo Arteaga @mgiraldo / @nypl_labs

GIMP executable path [/usr/bin/gimp]: 


Processing file: test.tif



Thresholdizing:
---------------
test.ti/test.tif into threshold file: test.ti/test/test-threshold-tmp.tif
batch command experienced an execution error



Geodata obtained:
-----------------
W -73.9968041
N 40.7219642
E -73.9955339
S 40.7205240


Applying to destination:
------------------------
ERROR 4: `test.ti/test/test-threshold-tmp.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

GDALOpen failed - 4
`test.ti/test/test-threshold-tmp.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.


ERROR 4: `test.ti/test/test-wsg-tmp.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.


Polygonizing (coarse):
----------------------
ERROR 4: `test.ti/test/test-gdal-tmp.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Unable to open test.ti/test/test-gdal-tmp.tif

Splitting megapolygon file into chunks
--------------------------------------
Could not open shapefile
```

EDIT:

**SCIENCE FACT: USE THE RIGHT VERSION.**

updated to 2.8.6

It now works.

with this dudes help
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/install-gimp-286-in-ubuntu-ppa.html

also to be noted: Precise Pangolin only maintains Gimp 2.6 in their repositories.

Answer (score 0):

A fix was submitted. Check the new version: https://github.com/NYPL/map-vectorizer